# How to pre select django forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: django, checkbox, django-forms, django-admin, multiplechoicefield

I am having a `MultipleChoiceField` to select language choices from a list of 7 languages.

```
LANGUAGES = (
   ('en', _('English')),
   ('pl', _('Polish')),
   ('da', _('Danish')),
)
```

Inside my forms.py, I have

```
language = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

I am trying to pre select choices when the page is loaded. 
I have tried

```
self.fields['language'].widget.attrs.update({'initial': selected_languages})
```

and

```
self.fields['language'].initial = selected_languages
```

inside `__init__`

my `selected_languages` has value like `['en', 'fr' ]`

Edit:
The initial added is getting added as an html attribute inside every language checkbox.

```
<label for="id_language_0"><input type="checkbox" name="language"   value="en" initial="['en', 'fr']" id="id_language_0">English</label>
```

I this the right way to pre select fields in django forms? This method is not working for me. Is there any other method?
NB: I am using this form inside `django admin`

Comment: It would be helpful if you included more context from the relevant files

Comment: Why don't you add the `initial` directly to the `MultipleChoiceField` as described here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#initial ?

Comment: Because the initial value is different for different instance.  So I can't do that